# Match 5 closest in same array

Tags: microsoft-excel, array, lookup

I have a list of customers and lat/long coordinates (3 columns:c,u,v respectively) I want to create 5 columns to resolve as the closest 5 customers.

So far I’m using

```
min(sqrt(([lat1]-[lat_array])^2+([long1]-[long_array])^2))
```

I also need to include this formula in another that will say

If [lat1,long1] is 2nd closest to [lat70,long70] displays [customer70]

EDIT-
Thanks to Scott Carner for giving me SMALL() which provides raw distance. Now to display customer names related to the distance I’m attempting

```
LOOKUP(small(sqrt(([lat1]-[lat_array])^2+([long1]-[long_array])^2),2), [list of distances], [customer_array])
```

The middle part has me hung up where I need to make an array for all distances from customer1

EDIT 2- 
finally got to a desktop, cleaned up the post. Also here's a picture of my test[image]

From this point on I'll be using formulas specific to this sheet

Still working on [list of distances]. When I try

```
=LOOKUP(SMALL(SQRT((A2-$A$2:$A$5)^2+(B2-$B$2:$B$5)^2),2),SQRT((A2-$A$2:$A$5)^2+(B2-$B$2:$B$5)^2),$C$2:$C$5)
```

The value for`SQRT((A2-$A$2:$A$5)^2+(B2-$B$2:$B$5)^2)` normally returns as a spilled array when by itself but doesn't appear to have the properties of an array inside the LOOKUP() as altering the code to exclude a makes LOOKUP() resolve to b which is the 2nd value on my list but the furthest from a

EDIT 3
stopped using LOOKUP started using INDEX(REF,MATCH())

Comment: maybe you should edit the question when you're back at a real computer, check the words (some of which don't make sense right now) and include some sample data.

Comment: Could you provide a sample about this problem? you can try to provide a sample file or image, it will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

credit to user Scott Craner for teaching me `SMALL` and `INDEX(MATCH())`